# Remove notification badge icon with specific type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification

In my app i want to send for users 2 types of notification.

1. From stuff(admin send it manually)
2. When statistic will update.

I want to remove badge with stuff notifications when user launch application, and statistic notification badge when user enter in some screen after login. But i only found method:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

So how it is possible to detect, what i need to remove...

Comment: In    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool, set this property to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some case we don't want to set badge icon to ZERO at all. There is method to get app-icon badge numbers.

> [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber =
>   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber - 1;

Once you receive push-alert, you will have some KEY whether its STUFF or STATIC update.

Once user click on push notification from notification tray or on alert. Check for that KEY(Stuff/Static) & using above line change badge number reduce badge number.

I hope this will give you idea.

Comment: yes, but where i get key ?? All is what available to send is: `Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)`(Python)

Comment: Based on requirement - That you have to request your API developer to add some Key/Identification in PAYLOAD of Push-Alert

Comment: so, this is possible to send any key: value in notification ? i can send for example: type="stuff". Where do i can read about parametrs ? I didn't find any information :(

Comment: Yes of course. You can send key-value pair dictionary in PAYLOAD but there is limitation of characters length.

Comment: but is there a storage of received notifications?

Comment: Yes, storage like NSUserDefaults, where i can go over all received notifications and check category, etc.

Comment: you need to check in 
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo